# Counting Views of Articles

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created a simple application that counts the views of an article. In the database articles table has a column view_count. Also I have a defined event & listener that increments view_count every time when some article is viewed:

The question, how to make update view_count , and store in database..?!

### App\Events\ ArticleViews.php:

```
class ArticleViewsextends Event
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $article;

    public function __construct(Article $article)
    {
        $this->article = $article;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

### App\Listeners\ IncrementArticleViewsCounts.php:

```
class IncrementArticleViewsCounts
{
    public function __construct()  { }

    public function handle(ArticleViewsextends $event)
    {
        $event->article->increment('view_count');
    }
}
```

### And in ArticleController.php@show:

```
$articles= new Scholarship();

Event::fire(new ArticleViewsextends ($scholarships));

parent::$data['articles'] = $articles->getAllActiveArticlesForFrontEnd(parent::$data['language']);
```

In views don't count.

Comment: Side note, why not use something like Google Analytics?  You can track page views for your entire site, articles included.  You'd also get additional information that can prove useful.

Comment: like what? Can I get an article or a link. I am the site programmer of the laravel.

Comment: Check out [their page](https://www.google.com/analytics/#?modal_active=none).  You can track page views, time on site, flow of traffic, bounce rate, and other key metrics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you need to to this in your listener

```
public function handle(ArticleViewsextends $event)
{
    $event->article->increment('view_count'); // Update your object
    $event->article->save(); // update the database
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Loek answer is correct .But heres a thing which you would like to consider . If you you really don't want to track who is viewing the articles and you just want to count the number of views for a particular article then its redundant to hit the database.(sql).That will lead to useless querying everytime you wish increase a view count.
I suggest you should try for nosql in such cases . Like Redis
The code in should look like

```
  Route::get('/article/{article}', function (Article $article) {
  Redis::zincrBy('views', 1, $article);//or any other key name
  return $article;
  });
```

This will give you additional facility to get the most up viewed articles as well
with

```
 $articles= Redis::zrevrange('views', 0, -1);
```

For more info check [here](https://redis.io/commands#sorted_set)